# How do I control another application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I need a C# application to click one of those buttons like the apps in the image, and search for another button to come up. Once it finds that button it has to click it too.
An image of the application I need to control: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLU0c.jpg

Comment: your question seems to be not so clear can please rephrase it?

Comment: Are you trying to test your application's UI or automate some other application? Are you trying to build a tool to do so or just looking for a way to do it (i.e. use AutoIt vs. re-implement)?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the application in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the  [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following sequence of actions:

1. Detect rectangles relative to left-top corner of window manually.
2. Catch your app window with WinAPI functions, detect left-top corner of window relative to screen origin and simulate mouse or keyboard button clicks to detected rectangles with [MouseKeyboardLibrary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library), another similar library, or just with WinAPI funcions.

[image: Manually detected rectangles]

Comment: Would this be using my mouse?

Comment: @koolboy5783, yes. But it's possible to save old mouse coordinates, make necessary actions and restore their.

Comment: I want it to be working without actually using my mouse, and I just started C#, so I don't know much about it.